# What's the benefit of encapsulating storage slots as structs?

Tags: solidity, evm, storage, struct, yul

Often times you'll see the following pattern for reading and writing to storage slots:

```
struct Slot {
  address value;
}

...

function getSlot(bytes32 slot) returns (Slot storage s) {
   assembly { s.slot := slot }
}
```

What exactly is the benefit of this? `getSlot(_IMPL_SLOT).value = addr` is convenient, but couldn't you also just use a simple setter:

```
function setSlot(address addr) {
  assembly { 
    sstore(_IMPL_SLOT.slot, addr)
  }
}
```

What's the benefit of the struct abstraction?